# Browser + server side cache clear not working

Tags: html, .htaccess, caching, local-storage

I'm using a web page builder that I've purchased and I've modified it to make it run on a web server instead of a local computer. The way the page builder stores the data is by using LocalStorage.

Im writing all localstorage data to a database and on load I clear browser localstorage with "window.localStorage.clear();" then I write new localstorage using the data saved before.

In general this works but I'm having some difficulties forcing the browser to display the latest content but it will eventually show after a few refreshes.

I found this code to put in .htaccess:

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

and I'm using these meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
```

It seems like this did the trick in Chrome but firefox is still not showing the correct content.

Locally the code works great, the problem appeared after uploading it to a web server.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance